# Monitor immediately goes to sleep, not detected thereafter

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, displayport

I have a dual monitor setup, on Windows 10, using an Nvidia Geforce 770.  One monitor is an old HP, connected via DVI.  This works fine.

The one I'm having trouble with is a Dell P2415Q, connected via DisplayPort, using the mini-DisplayPort cable that came with the monitor.  The monitor goes into power save mode immediately on startup, and Display Settings doesn't even detect it.

If I connect it via HDMI, it works, so I don't think it's the monitor.

If I only have the Dell monitor connected and boot up, I see the Windows logo screen for a couple seconds, and the monitor goes to sleep.  So I don't think it's the cable.

This started immediately after I installed the Windows 10 anniversary update.  I have updated to the latest Nvidia driver, I have rolled back the driver, I have clean installed the drivers.  I rolled back the anniversary update and reinstalled the driver.  No change.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You say it isn't the monitor, but couldn't the display port on the monitor be defective? Anything is possible. Any way you can connect to a different computer to verify that? Or connect a different monitor to the computer display port to see if the problem continues?

Comment: Fair enough.  This is my only monitor with a DisplayPort hole, and my only DisplayPort cable.  It would just be _extremely_ coincidental timing to have this happen immediately after a major windows update.

Comment: I agree about the coincidence. Obviously a cable would be an inexpensive thing to purchase for troubleshooting, but if that results in the same issue, then what? If you know anyone with a laptop that has a display port, maybe you could ask them to help you verify the cable and monitor are working properly. Using only the existing equipment could lead you on a major wild goose chase.

Comment: Well.  I tried another DisplayPort cable.

It was the DisplayPort cable.

Comment: Probably something you could have done before posting your question. Nonetheless, glad you were able to fix it.

Comment: Yeah, if I had a spare DP cable when I posted it: https://superuser.com/questions/1112085/monitor-immediately-goes-to-sleep-not-detected-thereafter?noredirect=1#comment1584201_1112085 ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯